# Include Bootstrap 4 alpha 3 in a Rails 3.2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My Rails 3.2 app currently uses Bootstrap 2

I'd like my Rails 3.2 app to use Bootstrap 4. The gems seem to not support Rails 3.2

How can I get my Rails 3.2 app using Bootstrap 4 alpha 3?

Comment: Recommend you read GitHub issues; Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3 is not considered ready for any production or live deployment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Comment: I am ok with some bugs. I'd just like to get started using it and when the final version comes out I will be all set.